# SCSS loop - store the variable and use again in a different loop

Tags: css, sass

In my first SCSS loop, the $i is counting up.
The second loop is for a separate different UL list.

The second loop should ideally start after the first loop has finished. One way I can think of is grab the value from the first $i and use that as a delay in the second loop.

**Is the above possible?**

1st UL loop.

```
&__menu-item {

  // Stagger animations by increasing the delay for the first 20 items
  @for $i from 1 through 20 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      animation: fade-in-down 0.4s linear 0.1s + ($i * 0.1);
      animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    }
  }
}
```

2nd UL loop.

```
&__social-item {

  // Stagger animations by increasing the delay for the first 20 items
  @for $i from 1 through 20 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      animation: fade-in-down 0.4s linear 0.1s + ($i * 0.1);
      animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    }
  }
}
```

**Example**

The first loop has 7 items in it. Therefore the second loop should start after 0.7 seconds.

```
animation: fade-in-down 0.4s linear 0.7s + ($i * 0.1);
```

[image: Current set-up]

[image: What I am after]

Comment: you mean that the `...0.1s + ($i * 0.1);`  should have its start-time after first loop, like start at x seconds?

Comment: @Dejan.S - Yeah, so the first UL actually has 7 items in it currently, so the delay for the second loop should be 0.7

Comment: but you are looping from 1 to 20 and scss is unaware about how many children are actually defined in the markup

Comment: @fcalderan - Ah! good point hmm.

Comment: I mean it seems as you can have hard coded values, like you know the item amount? Why not just start the second loop at your end number from the first one? Creating something dynamic is no way without javascript, like fcalderan say you need to be aware of the markup.

Comment: Nothing is hardcoded, other than the maximum of 20 count. This is for a header navigation and can of course have items added or removed at any time by clients.

Comment: You are not gone able to do that with scss, you need to be aware of the amount of items to do this correct. I would do something with javascript. Maybe like getting the items, calculating and adding the `animation-duration` inline.

Comment: if it was possibile redefine the value of a custom property defined inside the :root selector it could be possible do it in pure css on modern browser

Comment: @fcalderan good idea, that might be on to something.

Comment: @fcalderan - I've never actually used :root before to be fair, bit lost on this one.

Comment: @Dejan.S my idea was to use quantity queries to count how many list-items the first list contains and change a :root _--variable_ with a value, but afaik it's not possibile to redefine a custom property inside a selector so that it can be visible to another element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript option looks like this. The rest can be done in css, just leave the `animation-delay` out of it.

- get the items
- loop
- caluclate the time
- add as inline on the item

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item, .social-item');

items.forEach(function(currentValue, currentIndex) {
 let time = 0.1 + (currentIndex * 0.1);
 
 currentValue.style.animationDelay = time + 's';
 
 console.log(currentValue.style.animationDelay);
});
```

```html
<div class="menu-item">1</div>
<div class="menu-item">2</div>
<div class="menu-item">3</div>
<div class="menu-item">4</div>
<div class="menu-item">5</div>
<div class="menu-item">6</div>
<div class="menu-item">7</div>

<div class="social-item">1</div>
<div class="social-item">2</div>
<div class="social-item">3</div>
<div class="social-item">4</div>
<div class="social-item">5</div>
<div class="social-item">6</div>
<div class="social-item">7</div>
```